# Какая временная сложность поиска в std::list?

Tags: c++

Какая временная сложность поиска в std::list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо учитывать не только контейнер, но и алгоритм поиска. Если рассматривать наихудший случай, то для поиска элемента необходимо обойти весь контейнер, т.е сложность O(n).

Answer (score 1):

O(n), потому как это двусвязный список, и в худшем случае придется его пройти весь.